# Spring Boot: Is there a method for converting a API-Request with Complex and flexible structure to a java-list?

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I am working on a Java- Spring Boot Project right now.
I have an API_Endpoint with 4 exact same fields.
So Field1(Username), Field2(Firstname), Field3(Lastname), and Field4.
Field 1-3 is easy, I could assign them via `@JsonProperty("Username")` and so on.

But Field4 is different. This is a nested structure and it differs from time to time.

For example, in one request it's like:

```
Field4: [field5, field6, field7]
```

and the next time it's like

```
Field4: [field5: [Field6, field7, field8], field9, field10:[]
```

and this may be up to 200 fields.

In other words: Field4 is a complex and nested structure that (can) differ in every request.

Does `com.fasterxml.jackson`. provide a solution for this schema?

Comment: Do you have a class representation of every possible request object/inner object?

Comment: Is there a finite (and low-ish) number of combinations of nestings in Field 4? Or is the structure completely random with no structure between two requests? In the first case you could map it onto a set of dedicated classes and in the second case you might just want to map it onto nested maps (i.e. leave it essentially unmapped)

Comment: Hi @gmanjon, 
no there is no class representation. And this is intended to be so.

Comment: If there is no class representation, what donyou want to map it to? As @Joaquim said, you are looking for plain nested Map. Wouldnthat suit your needs? Or arenyountalking about any other kind of representation apart from classes and maps.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim ('s comment, surely) means something simple, like:

```
private Map<String,Object> field4;
```

(assuming you mapped field1-3 successfully/accordingly.)